# map over list and insert variables into a function

Tags: r, tidyverse, lapply, purrr

I have a list that I want to loop over and insert the variables into a function. However, the function I am using does not like the outputs I am getting from applying the map() function from {purr} package.

Here is my list:

```
$AAPL
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   ticker string    
   <chr>  <date>    
 1 AAPL   2020-01-28
 2 AAPL   2020-04-30
 3 AAPL   2020-07-30
 4 AAPL   2020-10-29
 5 AAPL   2021-01-27
 6 AAPL   2020-01-29
 7 AAPL   2020-05-01
 8 AAPL   2020-07-31
 9 AAPL   2020-10-30
10 AAPL   2021-01-28

$ABEV
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  ticker string    
  <chr>  <date>    
1 ABEV   2020-02-26
2 ABEV   2020-05-06
3 ABEV   2020-07-29
4 ABEV   2020-10-28
5 ABEV   2020-02-27
6 ABEV   2020-05-07
7 ABEV   2020-07-30
8 ABEV   2020-10-29


my.list = list(AAPL = structure(list(ticker = c("AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL"), string = structure(c(18289, 
18382, 18473, 18564, 18654, 18290, 18383, 18474, 18565, 18655
), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(305:380, .Names = c("305", 
"306", "307", "308", "309", "310", "311", "312", "313", "314", 
"315", "316", "317", "318", "319", "320", "321", "322", "323", 
"324", "325", "326", "327", "328", "329", "330", "331", "332", 
"333", "334", "335", "336", "337", "338", "339", "340", "341", 
"342", "343", "344", "345", "346", "347", "348", "349", "350", 
"351", "352", "353", "354", "355", "356", "357", "358", "359", 
"360", "361", "362", "363", "364", "365", "366", "367", "368", 
"369", "370", "371", "372", "373", "374", "375", "376", "377", 
"378", "379", "380"), class = "omit")), ABEV = structure(list(
    ticker = c("ABEV", "ABEV", "ABEV", "ABEV", "ABEV", "ABEV", 
    "ABEV", "ABEV"), string = structure(c(18318, 18388, 18472, 
    18563, 18319, 18389, 18473, 18564), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(305:380, .Names = c("305", 
"306", "307", "308", "309", "310", "311", "312", "313", "314", 
"315", "316", "317", "318", "319", "320", "321", "322", "323", 
"324", "325", "326", "327", "328", "329", "330", "331", "332", 
"333", "334", "335", "336", "337", "338", "339", "340", "341", 
"342", "343", "344", "345", "346", "347", "348", "349", "350", 
"351", "352", "353", "354", "355", "356", "357", "358", "359", 
"360", "361", "362", "363", "364", "365", "366", "367", "368", 
"369", "370", "371", "372", "373", "374", "375", "376", "377", 
"378", "379", "380"), class = "omit")))
```

I want to loop over this and add the variables into a Quanld fucntion. The Quandl function works with the following inputs.

```
Quandl.datatable('ORATS/VOL', tradedate=c('2021-02-19', "2020-01-20"), ticker='AAPL')
```

So what I am trying to do is loop over the list and insert the dates (string) and the ticker (ticker) into this function.

Here is what I have:

```
library(tidyverse)

map(my.list, ~Quandl.datatable('ORATS/VOL', tradedate=.x$string, ticker=.x$ticker[1]))
```

This gives an error because it looks like the format is not in a vector when being input into the function. What am I missing here? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at how the `tradedate` values in the manual entry, it is `character` class, while the 'string' column is `Date` class.  May be, we can change it to `character` with `as.character`

```
library(purrr)
out <- map(my.list, ~Quandl.datatable('ORATS/VOL', 
     tradedate = as.character(.x$string), ticker=.x$ticker[1]))
```

The reason could be that in the API call, it is converting to `character` anyway, but if we use a `Date` class, the coercion to `integer` storage values may prevent it from executing